# MEAN Stack App with Angular 2

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I'm trying to get a MEAN stack app working, but with using Angular 2 instead of Angular 1 (which I've done before, although it's been a while). I have the Express app working, and it runs on port 3000. My Angular 2 app can get up and running easily as well, but runs (right now) on port 8080.

I know that what I want is the whole app to run on the one express server, with it serving the main layout and then the Angular running inside that, but I'm not sure the best way to go about that.

Instead of copying every file here, [here's a link to the repository](https://github.com/pjlamb12/ng2-mean) where everything's committed. Cloning the repo, running `npm install && bower install`, and then in one terminal window `gulp serve` and a second window `npm start`.

Any help on where to go from here would be greatly appreciated.